# Why there is no Update() function in Dictionary object?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I'm use Dictionary object quite a lot and always need to add / remove / update items.

I was wondering why there is no built in `Update()` function for Dictionary, not even as a LINQ extension (with relevance to thread safety, locks, other. E.g. `UpdateSafe()` or similar)

The `ConcurrentDictionary` object has `AddOrUpdate()`.

Note: I looking for previous SO post that explains the concept but did not find one.

Answer or reference to post which explains the concept will be appreciated.

Comment: So you want an `Update` method that is thread safe? What exactly do you expect it to do?

Comment: Did you searched for "how to update dictionary"? There *is* a way to do this, it´s just not called `Update` but *indexer*.

Comment: You can see the insiders debating this issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1942

Comment: @Sweeper I update for many reasons, and sometimes I want thread safety, sometimes not, Was just weird to me that there is Update function (of any kind) while add / remove do exist, and update is a trivial functionality

Answer (score 8):

There is, you can use the `this[]` accessors.

```
dict[key] = value;
```

This will either add or replace the current value for the specified key.

The main difference with `ConcurrentDictionary` is that `ConcurrentDictionary` is thread-safe. `Dictionary` is not.

The CLR team probably felt the need to create a method with the `AddOrUpdate` name in `ConcurrentDictionary` since there are more methods on adding and updating. Else you might think there is no way to do that, but functionally it is the same to the `this[]` accessor.

Comment: Thanks @Patrick Hofman, familiar with the syntax, your note on "more methods on adding and updating" makes sense.